# How to get current index of the carousel when the swipe event occurs - react slick

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-slick

I had some problems with customizing the library dots, so I'm creating one manually.
I'm trying to get the current index of the carousel when the swipe event occurs.
I tried the onSwipe props, but it just returns the swipe direction

My Slider component:

```
export function PromotionalCarousel({
    infinite = false,
    speed = 500,
    slidesToShow,
    slidesToScroll,
    children,
    showArrows = true,
    dots = false
}: PropTypes) {
    const sliderRef = useRef(null);
    const [slide, setSlide] = useState(0)

    const changeSlide = (index: number) => {
        sliderRef.current.slickGoTo(index);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        changeSlide(slide)
    }, [slide])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (sliderRef.current === 0) {
            setSlide(0);
        } 
        if (sliderRef.current === 1) {
            setSlide(1);
        }
        if (sliderRef.current === 2) {
            setSlide(2);
        }
    }, [sliderRef])
    
    return (
        <div className={styles['main-area']}>
            <section className={styles['slide-container']}>
                <Slider
                    ref={sliderRef}
                    dots={dots}
                    infinite={infinite}
                    speed={speed}
                    slidesToShow={slidesToShow}
                    slidesToScroll={slidesToScroll}
                    className={styles.slider}
                    arrows={showArrows}
                    onSwipe={(index) => setSlide(Number(index))}
                >
                    {children.map((element, i) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={i} className={styles.image}>
                                {element}
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
                </Slider>
            </section>
            <div className={styles['buttons-area']}>
                    <button 
                        type='button' 
                        className={styles['button-carousel']}
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: slide === 0 ? '#fa6c00' : '#8A9197', 
                            opacity: slide === 0 ? '1' : '.3'
                        }}
                        onClick={() => setSlide(0)}
                    />
                    <button 
                        type='button' 
                        className={styles['button-carousel']}
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: slide === 1 ? '#fa6c00' : '#8A9197',
                            opacity: slide === 1 ? '1' : '.3'
                        }}
                        onClick={() => setSlide(1)}
                    />
                    <button 
                        type='button' 
                        className={styles['button-carousel']}
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: slide === 2 ? '#fa6c00' : '#8A9197', 
                            opacity: slide === 2 ? '1' : '.3'
                        }} 
                        onClick={() => setSlide(2)}
                    />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

How can I get the current index of the carousel by the swipe function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-slick` provides 2 methods that allow you to get slide index:

- `beforeChange: (current, next) => {}`
- `afterChange: current => {}`

The different between these 2 methods are:

- `beforeChange()` will be triggered before the slide is changed (in all cases of swiping, click prev/next buttons or go to specific slide). It has 2 arguments: `current` is index of the starting point, and `next` is index of the target slide *(not always equal to `current + 1`)*.
- `afterChange()` will be triggered after the slide is changed so now `current` is index of the target slide (equals to `next` of the `beforeChange()`)

Comment: I used afterChange to set the value of the slide, thank you very much, it worked!